# Обособляется ли имя собственное?

Tags: пунктуация, грамматика

Как именно отделяется, или вообще не отделяется, имя или другая персоналия в предложении? Например, в таком:

**Эта злобная стерва (,/—) Татьяна Андреевна (,/—) и её муженёк-ублюдок, зарабатывающий на несчастье людей, поселились у нас на неделю.**

Что в данном случае мне нужно сделать с Татьяной — оставить в покое или обособить? Если вас не затруднит, было бы неплохо предоставить исчерпывающую информацию, но я готов поверить на слово. Так же был бы рад увидеть примеры схожих конструкций из литературы.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Правило

Это тема обособленных приложений: [Розенталь. § 19. Обособленные приложения](http://old-rozental.ru/punctuatio.php?sid=111#pp111)

6. Собственное имя лица или кличка животного выступает в роли обособленного приложения, если **поясняет либо уточняет-нарицательное существительное** (перед таким приложением можно без изменения смысла вставить слова а именно, то есть, а зовут его): Дочь Дарьи Михайловны, Наталья Алексеевна, с первого взгляда могла не понравиться (Т.); Примечание. Во многих случаях возможна **двоякая пунктуация**, в зависимости от наличия/отсутствия пояснительного оттенка значения и соответствующей интонации при чтении.

Пояснение

1) Итак, возможны два варианта: 1) имя не обособляется, если приложение имеет только определительное значение; 2) имя обособляется, если оно (имя) имеет значение уточнения.

2) Соответственно,  в каждом случае мы должны  определить по тексту **наличие или отсутствие значения уточнения**, а варианты могут быть разные: имя персонажа неважно, дается только как дополнение; к данному приложению подходят два лица, нужно уточнить, о каком именно идет речь и т.д.  Кроме того, нужно учитывать **структуру предложения.**

2) В приведенном примере обособление также зависит от контекста и от структуры.

Читатель может не сразу понять, **к кому относится столь негативное определение,** тогда имя должно быть обособлено (значение в этом случае такое: я имею в виду Татьяну Андреевну).

**Да и по структуре** предложения обособленный вариант подходит больше, так как начало предложения (два однородных  подлежащих, связанных союзом И, а это 8 слов!) сложно прочесть как единую фразу.

Эти два фактора склоняют нас к обособленному варианту: **Эта злобная стерва, Татьяна Андреевна, и её муженёк-ублюдок, зарабатывающий на несчастье людей, поселились у нас на неделю.**

Comment: Желательно указать, какие знаки препинания возможны и предпочтительны.

Comment: Спасибо за замечание, я исправила ответ.